# WIKIDATA “instance of” end “subclass of” inheritance

Tags: wikidata

Are these two statements true?

1. if X is instance of Y and Y is subclass of Z then X is instance of Z?
2. if X is subclass of Y and Y is instance of Z than X is instance of Z?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Amedeo's comment below is correct. The following is incorrect (I'll leave it up as context for his reply).

No. Wikidata generally does not implement transitivity. You need to use the P:31/P279* selector to include all instances of subclasses.

Comment: Actually Wikidata said: "subclass of" is transitive property as described in https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P279